# How can I print a new line in JS without using document.write?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to print a new line in JS, but I can't figure out how to do it without document.write. I need to do it without this because I'm using buttons to call functions, and when I use doc.write, it erases the page and displays the results of the function on its own.

```
<h3>$$$$$</h3>
<span id = "$"></span>
<button onclick="prob2()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function prob2(){
        n = parseInt(prompt("Enter number: "));
        for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<=i;j++){
                document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = "$";
            }
            console.log("\n");
        }
    };
```

Rather than having console.log there, I want to print a line break on the screen so that my output looks like this:

```
$
$$
$$$
...
```

EDIT:
Based on Anurag's first suggestion, I built a string and used it with innerHTML to achieve my desired output.

```
function prob2(){
        var str = "";
        var num = parseInt(prompt("Enter number: "));
        for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
            for(var j=0;j<=i;j++){
                str += "$";
            }
            str += "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = str;
    };
```

His second suggestion that I accepted as the answer also works!

Comment: Google "innerHTML" for a quick solution. There are other more complicated ways to do it but you can get 99% of what you want with `innerHTML`

Comment: `innerHTML` sets the HTML of your selector, and you are setting it to `$` in every iteration. You need to build a string and set that as `innerHTML`. As for new line, use a `<br>` tag

Comment: `innerHTML` and `insertAdjacentHTML` are the solution

Comment: What about `document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = "$<br>";` ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Thank you! This made the most sense to me, and has allowed me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
function generate() {
  document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = ""
  var n = parseInt(prompt("Enter number: ")), str = "", currStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str = "", currStr = document.getElementById("$").innerHTML
    for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      str+= "$"
      document.getElementById("$").innerHTML = currStr + str + "<br/>";
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<h3>Incremental $</h3>
<span id="$"></span>
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the question differently.  I thought the purpose was to replace the use of the document.write() statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title> Test Page </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width,initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<!-- For: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742502/how-can-i-print-a-new-line-in-js-without-using-document-write -->
<style>
 p { background-color: lime; }
 pre { border: 1px solid red;}
 div { border: 3px dotted blue }
</style>

</head><body>

<script>
newLine = (tag,msg) => {
  var elem = document.createElement(tag);
  elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
// Note: .body. could be a different element or another parameter added to function
}
newLine('p','New line has been created.');
newLine('pre','And then another.');
newLine('div','And then one final new line to display.');
</script>

</body></html>
```

Remove the CSS styling as it was only added for emphasis.

Comment: That was the initial question, but the goal was to achieve the desired output, which I was able to do without using document.write(). My main issue was the page being cleared. Thank you for this though!!!